# Unity3D - how to use arrays with custom inspector code?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, initialization, customization, execution

I seem to be stuck in a catch 22 situation with the OnInspectorGUI method of Unity's UnityEditor class. I want to name array elements in the inspector for easy editing, currently I'm using, as per the documentation:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
   J_Character charScript = (J_Character)target;

   charScript.aBaseStats[0] = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Base Health", charScript.aBaseStats[0]);

}
```

In my J_Character script I initialise the aBaseStats array like so:

```
public float[] aBaseStats = new float[35];
```

The problem is that whenever I try to do anything in the editor (and thus OnInspectorGUI is called) I get an index out of range error pointing to the line

```
charScript.aBaseStats[0] = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Base Health", charScript.aBaseStats[0]);
```

I'm guessing this is because my array is initialized on game start while the editor code is running all the time while developing.

How can I get round this situation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize `aBaseStats` in an function that runs only once.

The code below is **BAD**:

```
public float[] aBaseStats = new float[35];
void Start(){

}
```

The code below is **GOOD**:

```
public float[] aBaseStats;
void Start(){
aBaseStats = new float[35];
}
```

Initialize it in an Editor callback function that runs once.

**EDIT:**

I don't know a `Start` callback function that will run before the `OnInspectorGUI` function(). The hack below should work.

```
public float[] aBaseStats;
bool initialized = false;
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
   if (!initialized)
   {
       initialized = true;
       aBaseStats = new float[35];
   }

   J_Character charScript = (J_Character)target;

   charScript.aBaseStats[0] = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Base Health",aBaseStats[0]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried in both Start and Awake but it doesn't work - again, presumably because those functions only run on game start, not in the editor. Can you expand on what you mean by "Initialize it in an Editor callback function that runs once." please?

Comment: @Absinthe There are many Editor callback functions and I don't know which one you are using. It would be good if you list all Unity `OnSomething` functions you are using then I will tell you the right one that runs once.

Comment: @Absinthe try something simpler. Try `charScript.aBaseStats[0] = 1f;` and see if you still get the-same error. If you do then you did not initialize it well. Make sure sure that you initialize it before the line of code `charScript.aBaseStats[0] = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Base Health", charScript.aBaseStats[0]);`

Comment: charScript.aBaseStats[0] = 1f; didn't work, same error. If I initialize in the OnInspectorGui method there is no error but of course on each call to it any values I assign to the arrays are re-initialized. I've tried looking for some equivalent of MonoBehaviours Awake function for editor code but I can't find anything. The only OnSomething (and indeed the only method) I'm using in the custom editor script is OnInspectorGui

Comment: They are not re-initialized. The bool prevents that.

Comment: @ Programmer Hmm, I had the same idea. It is hacky indeed but it does work :)

Comment: @Gunnar - hadn't seen the new comment, was refering to Programmers previous one

Comment: @Absinthe If it works please accept this as answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png Thanks.

Comment: I will if nothing else comes up in the next few hours, many thanks, have rated up.

Comment: @GunnarB. You probably didn't read the solution well. The bool runs once the toggles to false so that it wont run again. You can't continue to initialize array every frame.

Comment: @Absinthe **I will if nothing else comes up in the next few hours, many thanks, have rated up** lol this question has been solved and that code will always work. Anyways take your time.

Comment: @Programmer I didn't say anything else ;)

Comment: @GunnarB. my bad. I am the one that actually read your comment wrong. I read it again and you are right.

Comment: Should have been obvious to me earlier but this won't work as on restarting the editor the array is reset which defeats the purpose of setting up a custom inspector. Still looking for ideas...

Comment: @Absinthe Are you kidding me? **I get an index out of range error pointing to the line**. This answer solved that problem. Your problem in this question is solved. This has nothing to do with your original question/problem. You can close this question and ask another question about how to save an array.

Comment: If it wasn't initialized, wouldn't it give you NullReference?@Absinthe Can you show J_Character script? I've tried your code snippet and it works for me. Which Unity version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer by Programmer I would like to point you to the following:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for in terms of functionality. (it runs the method even when playmode is not active)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    void Update() {
        if (target)
            transform.LookAt(target);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried to initialize in Awake and Start with [ExecuteInEditMode] but got the same errors

Comment: have you tried combining our answers? If you set a variable to keep track of initialisation and use the update function to initialise your values if they have not yet been initialised it should work. If it doesn't could you post a code sample with the matching error?